# Angular CLI generate a list of tree shaken components & services

Tags: angular, webpack

Is there a way of generating a report of tree shaken components/services after a build(ng build) from Angular CLI.

Having in mind that most of the unused pieces should be picked up by just adding a lint rule itself, my intent with the report would be to find code that is lying in a declarations or providers array of some module but not really used.

Also for tricky cases like dynamic components where build would tree-shake components since they may not be found in any templates but dynamically created in a service.

Comment: what purpose does the report serve ?

Comment: I wish this feature existed. I think it's a valid request. The only thing we have is the bundle inspector. You would have to manually compare between a developer build (which doesn't include shaking) and a prod build. https://coryrylan.com/blog/analyzing-bundle-size-with-the-angular-cli-and-webpack the only problem by comparing is that you also see the diff of everything development related. So it's not just the exclusion of your stuff.